# Gostaria de saber como faço para deixar meus vídeos nessa configuração idêntica no ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, cmd, vídeo

Format : MPEG-4

Format profile : Base Media

Codec ID : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)

File size : 202 MiB

Duration : 22 min 9 s

Overall bit rate : 1 278 kb/s

Writing application : Lavf57.2.100

***Video***

ID : 1

Format : AVC

Format/Info? : Advanced Video Codec

Format profile : High@L4

Format settings : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames

Format settings, CABAC : Yes

Format settings, ReFrames? : 3 frames

Codec ID : avc1

Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding

Duration : 22 min 8 s

Bit rate : 1 146 kb/s

Width : 1 920 pixels

Height : 1 080 pixels

Display aspect ratio : 16:9

Frame rate mode : Variable

Frame rate : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS

Minimum frame rate : 23.974 FPS

Maximum frame rate : 23.981 FPS

Color space : YUV

Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0

Bit depth : 8 bits

Scan type : Progressive

Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.023

Stream size : 182 MiB (90%)

Color range : Limited

Color primaries : BT.709

Transfer characteristics : BT.709

Matrix coefficients : BT.709

***Audio***

ID : 2

Format : AAC

Format/Info? : Advanced Audio Codec

Format profile : LC

Codec ID : mp4a-40-2

Duration : 22 min 9 s

Bit rate mode : Constant

Bit rate : 126 kb/s

Channel(s) : 2 channels

Channel positions : Front: L R

Sampling rate : 44.1 kHz

Frame rate : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)

Compression mode : Lossy

Stream size : 19.9 MiB (10%)

Language : Portuguese

Default : Yes

Alternate group : 1

Comment: Como assim `ffmpeg`, seja mais claro com sua pergunta. Pois você somente deu uma ficha técnica mas não específicou por qual meio deseja obter esses ajustes sobre o aquivo, a não ser o próprio `ffmpeg`. Você esta usando alguma distro GNU/Linux???

Comment: Não sou expert em codificar vídeos. sou bem leigo.. Esse foi um vídeo que peguei e tinha essas configurações, e gostaria de fazer um vídeo com as mesmas configurações. Não sei usar direito o ffmpeg ainda estou aprendendo. Por isso fiz a pergunta, gostaria de saber o comando que posso usar para obter esse resultado.

Comment: obrigado amigo... uso windows 7 64bits

Comment: obrigado amigo... uso windows 7 64bits  Tenho o ffmpeg instalado e só faço    o basico mesmo.

Comment: Saiba como executar comandos Linux no Windows. Em paralelo a isso, é comum que muitos usuários (você ou outra pessoa conhecida) pensem algo assim: “Estou querendo aprender sobre o Linux, mas não quero que o Windows saia da minha máquina”.
Para tentar atingir boa parte desse público de usuários foi criado ferramentas que emulam um ambiente Linux no sistema Windows;
[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) e [Cash](https://github.com/dthree/cash) são dois programas para esta finalidade.

Comment: O **Cygwin** é uma DLL que emula o Linux dentro do Windows. O ***Cash**, não fugindo muito disso, promove tudo isso e mais um pouco.

Comment: Então para coseguir meu obejtivo preciso ter esses programas instalados na minha máquina?

Comment: instalei o ffmpeg de acordo com um tutorial e uso ele no Terminal CMD do windows

Comment: Tudo bem, compreendo! Veremos no que posso ser útil. Lhe darei um exemplo prático pra você realizar  um teste em seu CMD. Ok!? Aguarde ...

Comment: ok. vou aguardar.

Answer (score 1):

Com base nas informações dada na pergunta. Temos a conclusão que:

**Vídeo**

```
Resolução: 1920x1080p
Frame rate :  23 FPS
Bit rate : 1146 kb/s
Format : AVC    
Codec : mpeg4
```

**Áudio**

```
Bit rate : 126 kb/s
Format : aac    
Codec: mp4a-40-2
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Sampling rate : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
```

.. pode-se elaborar o seguinte pseudo-código no terminhal CMD:

```html
ffmpeg -y -i "video_original.mpg" -vcodec mpeg4 -r 23.976 -b 1146k -s 1920x1080 -acodec mp4a-40-2 -ab 126k -ar 44100 -map 0.0 -map 1.0 "video_convertido.mp4"
```

## Explicando cada parâmetro:

**Vídeo**

```
-vcodec - Faz cópia do vídeo original
-b      - Transferência do bitrate do vídeo
-r      - fps framerate do vídeo[Frames por segundo]
-s      - resolução do vídeo[tela]
```

**Áudio**

```
-acodec - Faz cópia do áudio original
-ab     - Transferência do bitrate do áudio
-ar     - Taxa de amostragem frequência em Mega Hertz
-map    - Definir os canais 1 ou 2 [L R] (mono ou estereo)
```

> **Nota** - Os codec mais comuns são MPEG4 e H264 para vídeos geralmente no formato ***mp4***.

Comment: bom dia... Ficou diferente..  ainda os comandos estavam dando erro,, na parta -b 1146k ele estava dizendo que seria -b:a ou -b:v e tambem na parte  -acodec informando que o parâmetro estava errado, ai coloquei -acodec aac ai deu certo.. mais ficou assim..

Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media
Codec ID                    : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                   : 247 MiB
Duration                    : 21 min 40 s
Overall bit rate mode       : Constant
Overall bit rate            : 1 593 kb/s
Writing application         : Lavf58.2.103

Comment: @Alex Para mais informações, só posso passar via [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72342/diego-henrique). Uma vez que, a pergunta pode ter que aplicar várias modos ajustes experimentais[é um trabalho árduo]. Que no seu requisito têm terá de ter uma abordagem ampla, mais profunda.

Comment: Olá Diego não consigo falar com vc via chat, não abre nenhuma opção para eu digitar ou falar com vc... Mais respodendo sua pergunta o vídeo original é em mp4 também, mais com configuração diferente.. E te faço uma pergunta, quais app para android que podem fazer isso?

Comment: Show de resposta, só queria entender essa parte: Format : AVC

Comment: @kaputtz O "MP4", que é o melhor formato de vídeo. O MP4 tem um padrão de container de áudio e vídeo que é parte da especificação MPEG-4 desenvolvido pela ISO/IEC 14496-14. É similar ao popular AVI, mas traz algumas vantagens: Suporte nativo a legenda embutida. Melhor suporte ao padrão de codificação de vídeo H.264, também conhecido como **MPEG4 AVC**. O arquivo MP4 pode ter sido criado com diversos tipos de codec diferentes, incluindo DivX e XviD. É comum você encontrar um MP4 que seja constituído por streams criados por codecs incomuns.